# Scala thread safety

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I'm running this code in Scala:

```
  def injectFunction(body: =>Unit): Thread = {
    val t = new Thread {
      override def run() = body
    }
    t
  }

  private var counter: Int = 0
  def increaseCounter(): Unit = this.synchronized {
    //putting this as synchronized doesn't work for some reason..
    counter = counter + 1
    counter
  }

  def printCounter(): Unit = {
    println(counter)
  }

  val t1: Thread = injectFunction(increaseCounter())
  val t2: Thread = injectFunction(increaseCounter())
  val t3: Thread = injectFunction(printCounter())
  t1.start()
  t2.start()
  t3.start()
```

This prints out 1 most of the time, though sometimes 2 and 0 a few times. Shouldn't the this.synchronized before the increaseCounter() method ensure that it's thread safe, and print 2 every time? I've also tried adding this.synchronized in the definition of printCounter(), with no luck.

Comment: Nothing guarantees order of execution of the threads. `t3` could print before `t1` or `t2` had the chance to run. To convince yourself, add some logging statement ;)

Comment: On a side note, we don't usually write code that uses Thread directly in Scala but we use higher abstractions like `Future`.

Comment: I don't know Scala syntax. Is there a different `this` instance in each thread? or is `this` the same object in all three threads? Synchronization in the JVM has no effect between threads that are `synchronized` on different instances. It only works when the threads are all synchronized on the same, shared instance.

Comment: If you want to write **Java** code then use **Java**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very entertaining example! It's so broken that it actually fails at failing to fail:

- It was already failing right from the beginning, because it started with the wrong assumption that the `synchronized` keyword would somehow force the `t3` to execute last. But that's simply not the case, the `synchronized` has nothing to do with the order in which the threads are executed. The threads can still run in arbitrary order, the `synchronized` merely ensures that they don't enter the `synchronized` block simultaneously.
- Then it additionally fails at generating a random `0` / `1` / `2` output, because there is no `synchronized` block around the `counter` in the `println`, i.e. there is no actual guarantee that the printing thread will see the random changes made by the two other threads. As it is, the printing thread had every right to print `0`, without being obliged to do so.
- The statements that are executed in the initializer of the `object` attempt to acquire `this` in `this.synchronized`. If one additionally adds `tN.join()` into the initializer, everything freezes with a deadlock (because the initialization cannot finish before `t1`, `t2`, `t3` can `join`, and they cannot `join` before they can enter a `this.synchronized`, and they cannot enter `this.synchronized` before the initialization has unlocked `this`).

Here is the example that fixes all three problems:

```
object Example {
  def injectFunction(body: =>Unit): Thread = {
    val t = new Thread {
      override def run() = body
    }
    t
  }

  private var counter: Int = 0
  def increaseCounter(): Unit = {
    // 
    Thread.sleep(util.Random.nextInt(1000))
    this.synchronized {
      counter += 1
    }
  }

  def printCounter(): Unit = {
    Thread.sleep(util.Random.nextInt(1000))
    println("Random state: " + this.synchronized { counter })
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val t1: Thread = injectFunction(increaseCounter())
    val t2: Thread = injectFunction(increaseCounter())
    val t3: Thread = injectFunction(printCounter())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    println("Final state:  " + counter)
  }
}
```

Now this will indeed randomly output

```
Random state: 0
Final state:  2
```

or

```
Random state: 1
Final state:  2
```

or

```
Random state: 2
Final state:  2
```

The crucial differences to your code are:

- random `sleep`s make the parallelism at least somewhat visible. Without this, you might get `2` & `2` repeatedly.
- the reading access to `counter` in `println(counter)` must also be synchronized
- if you want to demonstrate that the final state of the counter is `2`, you have to wait for all three threads to `join`.
- All the statements are in the `main`, so that the `object` can be initialized correctly.